# zsh: missing end of string (MacOS)

Tags: terminal

Hello I'm trying to install Wine but when I put in a code I get a error in Terminal
It work one time then when I try again I got a error (Note: if anyone know how to install wine help me what to do)

brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask --no-quarantine (selected wine package) Error zsh: missing end of string